# How can I conditionally replace values in an Apache Spark dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin, apache-spark-dataset

I have this dataset:

```
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|   Name|Order|Orbiting|           Habitable|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|Mercury|    1|     Sol|                  No|
|  Venus|    2|     Sol|                  No|
|  Earth|    3|     Sol|                 Yes|
|   Mars|    4|     Sol|Only with terrafo...|
|Jupiter|    5|     Sol|                  No|
| Saturn|    6|     Sol|                  No|
| Uranus|    7|     Sol|                  No|
|Neptune|    8|     Sol|                  No|
|  Pluto|    9|     Sol|                  No|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```

What I'd like to achieve is to replace `Sol` with `Sun` if the `Name` contains `us` and starts with `Ve`.

I've tried this:

```
var col = col("Name")
col = col.contains("us").and(col.startsWith("Ve"))

val result = dataset.withColumn(
        "Orbiting",
        functions.regexp_replace(col,
                "Sol",
                "Sun"))
```

But with this I just see the results of the boolean filter:

```
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|   Name|Order|Orbiting|           Habitable|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|Mercury|    1|   false|                  No|
|  Venus|    2|    true|                  No|
|  Earth|    3|   false|                 Yes|
|   Mars|    4|   false|Only with terrafo...|
|Jupiter|    5|   false|                  No|
| Saturn|    6|   false|                  No|
| Uranus|    7|   false|                  No|
|Neptune|    8|   false|                  No|
|  Pluto|    9|   false|                  No|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```

What I'd like to get is this:

```
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|   Name|Order|Orbiting|           Habitable|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|Mercury|    1|     Sol|                  No|
|  Venus|    2|     Sun|                  No|
|  Earth|    3|     Sol|                 Yes|
|   Mars|    4|     Sol|Only with terrafo...|
|Jupiter|    5|     Sol|                  No|
| Saturn|    6|     Sol|                  No|
| Uranus|    7|     Sol|                  No|
|Neptune|    8|     Sol|                  No|
|  Pluto|    9|     Sol|                  No|
+-------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```

but only when the value of `Orbiting` is `Sol`. So for example if it is `Proxima Centauri` it should stay like that.

I've also tried this:

```
var col = col("Name")
col = col.contains("us").and(col.startsWith("Ve"))

val result = dataset.withColumn(
        "Orbiting",
        `when`(col, "Sun").otherwise("Sol"))
```

which works when `Orbiting` only has `Sol` as a value, but when I have `ProximaCentauri` it is not working any longer, because I can't filter for it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
val result = it.withColumn("Orbiting", 
      when(col("Name").startsWith("Ve") && 
      col("Name").contains("nus"), 
    regexp_replace(col("Orbiting"), "Sol", "Sun"))
    .otherwise(col("Orbiting")))
```

and definitely the following one

```
val result = it.withColumn("Orbiting",
    when(col("Name") === "Venus", 
    regexp_replace(col("Orbiting"), "Sol", "Sun"))).otherwise(col("Orbiting")))
```

and of course you need the following import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: This is just a `set` operation not a `replace` operation. I'd like to use `functions.regexp_replace` or something similar to perform regex matching.

Comment: @AdamArold, i have updated my answer. Your answer below made me understand your requirement. I hope it is fulfilled

Comment: This won't work because of `col("Orbiting") === "Sol"`. I want to perform a regex filter here, not an equality operator. I checked and `Column` does not have a `match` or `regexMatch` or anything similar.

Comment: yes @AdamArold, you are correct. I have removed that part. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a `temp` column and using `when` with that column:

```
var result = it.withColumn(
        "temp",
        functions.regexp_replace(col("Orbiting"),
                "Sol",
                "Sun"))

result = result.withColumn("Orbiting",
        `when`(col("Name").startsWith("Ve")
                .and(col("Name").contains("nus")),
                col("temp")).otherwise(col("Orbiting")))

result = result.drop(col("temp"))
result.show()
```

And the results:

```
+-------------------+-----+----------------+--------------------+
|               Name|Order|        Orbiting|           Habitable|
+-------------------+-----+----------------+--------------------+
|            Mercury|    1|             Sol|                  No|
|              Venus|    2|             Sun|                  No|
|              Earth|    3|             Sol|                 Yes|
|               Mars|    4|             Sol|Only with terrafo...|
|            Jupiter|    5|             Sol|                  No|
|             Saturn|    6|             Sol|                  No|
|             Uranus|    7|             Sol|                  No|
|            Neptune|    8|             Sol|                  No|
|              Pluto|    9|             Sol|                  No|
|Proxima Centauri b |    1|Proxima Centauri|               Maybe|
+-------------------+-----+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: You don't need to create temp column and drop it later. see my updated answer above ;)